# Why does data folder in android simulator deny permission?

Tags: android, database, adb, simulator, chmod

I tried to create database file into

C:\Users\cammm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/data/data/com.cookandroid.cammm

Here are steps that I tried to get into the folder

1. click on "cmd" and run as administrator
2. cd C:\Users\cammm\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools
3. adb root
4. adb shell cd /data/data/com.cookandroid.cammm

Now this pops up: "/system/bin/sh: cd: /data/data/com.cookandroid.adb: Permission denied"

I used "ls" in "platform-tools" folder and saw that it was 
"drwxrwx--x  37 system system  4096 2018-07-18 15:46 data"

which means file can only execute but not write or read in others.

1. using chmod did not work. (chmod: chmod '/data/data/com.cookandroid.adb' to 40702: Operation not permitted)
2. run as administor does not work

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You will only be able to access the data/data folder if the device which you are accessing is rooted. when you have the device rooted then it will show # as prompt on the command line. so Make sure you have the rooted device to execute the above steps.

Please note: It's not advisable to use the rooted devices to carry out any function of the application as it's simply a hack of the device so you have to understand the risk associated with it.